# Evaluating π using Monte Carlo methods - Serial vs OMP

Tags: c, comparative-review, numerical-methods, openmp

I wrote this simple code for evaluating the π using Monte Carlo method. This is the serial version:

```
long double compute_pi_serial(const long interval) {

  srand(time(NULL));

  double x, y;
  int i, circle = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < interval; i ++) {
    x = (double)(rand() / (double) RAND_MAX);
    y = (double)(rand() / (double) RAND_MAX);

    if (pow(x,2) + pow(y, 2) <= 1.0) circle ++;
  }

  return (long double) circle / interval * 4.0;
}
```

After, I wrote a parallel version using `OpenMP` and this is the result:

```
long double compute_pi_omp(const long interval) {

  double x, y;
  int i, circle = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel private(x, y) num_threads(omp_get_max_threads())
  {

    srand(SEED);

    #pragma omp for reduction(+:circle)
    for ( i = 0; i < interval; i++ ) {
      x = (double)(rand() / (double) RAND_MAX);
      y = (double)(rand() / (double) RAND_MAX);

      if ( pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) <= 1 ) circle++;
    }
  }

  return (long double) circle / interval * 4.0;
}
```

This is an efficient method or there is a most efficient version always using `OpenMP`?

Comment: Are you asking whether the Monte Carlo approach is efficient or the implementation with OpenMP?

Comment: @Ninetails My implementation in OpenMp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correctness issues**

Correctness merits priority over efficiency. Important to get a correct answer, not a  fast and wrong one.

- Poor use of mixing types

`long interval`, and `int i` lead to *undefined behavior* (UB) when `interval > INT_MAX`.  Use same type.

- Small range

`long` may use 32-bit.  Easy enough to run in less than 1 minute and exceed 2<sup>31</sup> - limiting how far we can test this code.  Use `long long` or, use `unsigned long long`.

- Off-by-1

Using `/ (double) RAND_MAX`  may impart a small bias.  Yet given the *slow  convergence* of the Monte Carlo PI, I doubt any serious miscalculation.

I'd expect the random values to be in the middle of each random range:

```
[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ... RAND_MAX - 1.5, RAND_MAX - 0.5, RAND_MAX + 0.5]/(RAND_MAX + 1u)
```

Code has then distributed differently:

```
[0.0, 1.0/RAND_MAX, 2.0/RAND_MAX, ... 1.0]
```

A more significant bias occurs when `(int)(double) RAND_MAX != RAND_MAX` - select platforms with more precision in `RAND_MAX` than `double`.

Note: to convert `RAND_MAX` plus 1 to `double`, code can use `(RAND_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0`.  Works well when `RAND_MAX` is a [Mersenne Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) or and odd value.  This avoids losing precision that `(double)RAND_MAX + 1.0` may incur.

---

**Efficiency**

- `pow()` vs `x*x`

A weak compiler may use a laborious function call seeing `pow(x,2)` and not the certainly more efficient `x*x` replacement.  Of course the right answer is to use a smart  compiler.  Still, profiling a direct coding of `x*x` may prove worth-wild.

- *fp* vs. *integer*

I'd even consider an integer only approach.  Something like the below.

```
// int2x twice as wide as int
int2x limit = (int2x) RAND_MAX * RAND_MAX;
...
  int2x x = rand();
  int2x y = rand();
  if (x*x + y*y <= limit) circle++;
```

- `double` vs. `long double`

Seriously doubt any calculation run within a day will benefit using the higher precision `long double`.

```
// return (long double) circle / interval * 4.0;
return circle / interval * 4.0;
```

- No comment on OP's major goal: Serial vs OMP - sorry.